# Visual studio 2017 & 2019 don't work well after reinstallation

Tags: visual-studio

After reinstalling win10 and vs2017 in my old HP255G, the vs design window exhibits weird behavior.
Empty property, tools with usercontrol disabled.
Unmanageable controls.
Same problem with my new Lenovo IdeaPad 3 hdpi plus blurry font in the code window.
Identical problems with Vs2019.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing F4 key the property tab will auto populate.

Comment: Thank you
it is a partial solution, it does not solve design problems.